# Macro variables : Apparent symbolic reference not resolved

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have an issue with an unresolved macro variable in the following (part of a) macro:

```
DATA _NULL_;
  SET TempVarFormat END=Last;
  LENGTH FormatValues $10000;
  RETAIN FormatValues;
  IF &OnlyNumeric = 1 THEN
    FormatValues = CATX(" ",FormatValues,STRIP(LookUpValue)||
    " = "||CATQ("A",TRIM(LookupDescription)));
  ELSE
    FormatValues = CATX(" ",FormatValues,CATQ("A"
    ,LookUpValue)||" = "||CATQ("A"
    ,TRIM(LookupDescription)));
  Test = STRIP(FormatValues);
  PUT Test /* To test buildup of variable */;
  IF Last THEN CALL SYMPUT('FormatValuesM',STRIP(FormatValues));
  IF Last THEN CALL SYMPUT('DataCollectionFK',DataCollectionFK);
RUN;
/* Make format with PROC FORMAT*/
%IF &OnlyNumeric = 1 %THEN %DO;
  PROC FORMAT LIB=WORK;
  VALUE DC&DataCollectionFK.A&AttributeFK.Format &FormatValuesM;
  RUN;
%END;
%ELSE %IF &OnlyNumeric = 0 %THEN %DO;
  PROC FORMAT LIB=WORK;
  VALUE $DC&DataCollectionFK.A&AttributeFK.Format &FormatValuesM;
  RUN;
%END;
```

I get the following **warning**

```
Apparent symbolic reference FORMATVALUESM not resolved.
```

And if I look in the log **&DataCollectionFK** is resolved but **&FormatValues is not**.

```
PROC FORMAT LIB=WORK; VALUE DC170A570Format &FormatValuesM;
```

Could someone advice? It is driving me nuts.

I tested it also without the STRIP() function and replacing the CALL SYMPUT with PUT to see if the variable is assigned a value. This all works fine.

Log copy (as requested in comment)

```
4         +
      DATA _NULL_; SET TempVarFormat END=Last; LENGTH

5         + FormatValues $10000; RETAIN FormatValues; IF 1 = 1 THEN FormatValues = CATX(" 
",FormatValues,STRIP(LookUpValue)|| " = "||CATQ("A",TRIM(LookupDescription))); ELSE 
FormatValues = CATX(" ",FormatValues,CATQ("A" ,LookUpValue)||" = "||CATQ("A" ,TRIM
6         +(LookupDescription))); Test = STRIP(FormatValues); PUT Test ; IF Last THEN CALL 
SYMPUT('DataCollectionFK',DataCollectionFK); IF Last THEN CALL SYMPUT('FormatValuesM',Test); 
RUN;

NOTE: Numeric values have been converted to character values at the places given by: 
      (Line):(Column).
      6:107   
1 = "Ja"
1 = "Ja" 0 = "Nee"
NOTE: There were 2 observations read from the data set WORK.TEMPVARFORMAT.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds

6         +
        PROC FORMAT LIB=WORK;  VALUE DC170A1483Format &FormatValuesM;  RUN;;

NOTE: Format DC170A1483FORMAT is already on the library.
NOTE: Format DC170A1483FORMAT has been output.
NOTE: PROCEDURE FORMAT used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

MPRINT LOG

```
MPRINT(CONSTRUCTVARIABLEFORMAT):   DATA TestDataSetFormat;
MPRINT(CONSTRUCTVARIABLEFORMAT):   SET TempVarFormat END=Last;
MPRINT(CONSTRUCTVARIABLEFORMAT):   LENGTH FormatValues $10000;
MPRINT(CONSTRUCTVARIABLEFORMAT):   RETAIN FormatValues;
MPRINT(CONSTRUCTVARIABLEFORMAT):   IF 1 = 1 THEN FormatValues = CATX(" 
",FormatValues,STRIP(LookUpValue)|| " = "||CATQ("A",TRIM(LookupDescription)));
MPRINT(CONSTRUCTVARIABLEFORMAT):   ELSE FormatValues = CATX(" ",FormatValues,CATQ("A" 
,LookUpValue)||" = "||CATQ("A" ,TRIM(LookupDescription)));
MPRINT(CONSTRUCTVARIABLEFORMAT):   Test = STRIP(FormatValues);
MPRINT(CONSTRUCTVARIABLEFORMAT):   PUT Test ;
MPRINT(CONSTRUCTVARIABLEFORMAT):   IF Last THEN CALL 
SYMPUT('DataCollectionFK',DataCollectionFK);
MPRINT(CONSTRUCTVARIABLEFORMAT):   IF Last THEN CALL SYMPUT('FormatValuesM',Test);
MPRINT(CONSTRUCTVARIABLEFORMAT):   RUN;
MPRINT(CONSTRUCTVARIABLEFORMAT):   PROC FORMAT LIB=WORK;
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference FORMATVALUESM not resolved.
MPRINT(CONSTRUCTVARIABLEFORMAT):   VALUE DC170A1483Format &FormatValuesM;
MPRINT(CONSTRUCTVARIABLEFORMAT):   RUN;
```

EDIT with some more attemps:
The problem lies in that the macro variable is not getting a value during the datastep, for some reason. Loading the macrovariable with an empty value before I run the macro, makes 
that the script does not give an error. But the variable is resolved as an empty variable.

removing the IF Last THEN parts, also does not alter the outcome.

Comment: I can't recreate the error. Could you post the bit of the log that relates to the data-step?

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I added the log as you requested @mjsqu

Comment: Where has the `ERROR` gone?!

Comment: The error is shown above these blocks. As many times as the macro is executed. As you can see in the log the line `PROC FORMAT LIB=WORK;  VALUE DC170A1483Format &FormatValuesM;  RUN;` one of the macro variable is not resolved. So the formats are empty.

Comment: Can you run it again with `OPTIONS MPRINT;` turned on? The line in the log won't necessarily contain the value of `&FormatValuesM` unless that option is on.

Comment: SYMBOLGEN is the more relevant option, I would think.  I don't see the message that would suggest it is not being resolved.  Unless you have a problem with macro scoping I don't think this should be a problem.

Comment: Are you doing all this just to create a format from a dataset?  There is a much, much easier way.

Comment: Hello Joe. The easier way is not known to me.
I am making a procedure that automatically collects dynamic data from a SQL server stored procedure. The formats are stored also in the database as value-description pairs. They are dynamically collected according to which dataset is requested from the server.

Comment: MPRINT Log added. It does show the variable is not resolved.

Comment: You should be able to do the above entirely without macros (perhaps with a macro variable or two if you have parameters); macro language statements should not be necessary at all for this.  Everything you do above can easily be done in the data step (yes, even doing several formats at once, even doing some char/some not char).

Comment: Also- [tag:enterprise-guide] is not appropriate for this question, whether or not you're using it here is irrelevant to the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely it'll be easier/simpler to use the `cntlin=` option of `PROC FORMAT` to pass in a dataset containing the relevant format name, start, end, label values...

A simple example...

```
/* Create dummy format data */
data formats ;
  fmtname = 'MYCHARFMT' ;
  type = 'C' ;
  do n1 = 'A','B','C','D','E' ;
    start = n1 ;
    label = repeat(n1,5) ;
    output ;
  end ;
  fmtname = 'MYNUMFMT' ;
  type = 'N' ;
  do n2 = 1 to 5 ;
    start = n2 ;
    label = repeat(strip(n2),5) ;
    output ;
  end ;
  drop n1 n2 ;
run ;

/* dummy data looks like this... */
 fmtname     type    start    label

MYCHARFMT     C        A      AAAAAA
MYCHARFMT     C        B      BBBBBB
MYCHARFMT     C        C      CCCCCC
MYCHARFMT     C        D      DDDDDD
MYCHARFMT     C        E      EEEEEE
MYNUMFMT      N        1      111111
MYNUMFMT      N        2      222222
MYNUMFMT      N        3      333333
MYNUMFMT      N        4      444444
MYNUMFMT      N        5      555555

/* Build formats from dataset */
proc format cntlin=formats library=work ; run ;
```

There are several other fields which can be defined in your format dataset to cater for low/high/missing values, ranges, etc.

See the SAS documentation > http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473464.htm

Comment: Amazing. I did not know of this option...
I will definitely look into this further. Still I don't understand why my macro is not working.

Comment: I would just not worry about it.  Your code wasn't really a very good way to do this; probably something is going wrong in your macro (perhaps scoping issues, perhaps something else you're not including in your question).  Just do it the better way :)

Comment: Allthough this answer did not answer this question, it gave a far better suggestion. Thank you for understanding what the plan was, and pointing me to a much better direction. It works like a charm!